# Python Numpy giving me different values than Excel for a 6th order polynomial

Tags: excel, numpy

Why is Python calculating different values for this 6th order polynomial than what Excel is giving me? (See comparison of plots between Excel and Python below.) Am I running into some precision issues? I'm on a Windows 11 x64-based PC.

#### Background:

I ran a 6th order polynomial linear regression in Excel and came out with the following coefficients (yes I know the subscript for the coefficients should match with the order of the term they belong to):

```
    a1 =  -0.000000000000000000051066485848517600000
    a2 = 0.0000000000000012806568632620900000
    a3 = -0.00000000000531035856252443000
    a4 = 0.0000000086330792556790300
    a5 = -0.0000063412693200472300000
    a6 = 0.0020307237682114700000000
    b1 = 19.2031257127800000000000000

for the following polynomial equation:
a1*f**6 + a2*f**5 + a3*f**4 + a4*f**3 + a5*f**2 + a6*f + b1
```

In Excel, I get expected values between 50 and 1800:

[image: Excel polynomial]

However, in Python, I get the following plot:

[image: Python polynomial]

##### Python code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

f = np.arange(50,1801)

def gain_response (f):
    a1 =  np.longdouble(-0.000000000000000000051066485848517600000)
    a2 = np.longdouble(0.0000000000000012806568632620900000)
    a3 = np.longdouble(-0.00000000000531035856252443000)
    a4 =  np.longdouble(0.0000000086330792556790300)
    a5 =  np.longdouble(-0.0000063412693200472300000)
    a6 = np.longdouble(0.0020307237682114700000000)
    b1 = np.longdouble(19.2031257127800000000000000)
    
    return a1*f**6 + a2*f**5 + a3*f**4 + a4*f**3 + a5*f**2 + a6*f + b1
    
plt.plot(f, gain_response(f), label="-40C")
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a bad idea to code this as you did.  You're prone to overflow/underflow issues.

A better way is to use [Horner's rule](https://cs.fit.edu/%7Ewds/classes/adm/Lectures/HornerPolynomial.pdf):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt


def gain_response(f):
    a1 = np.longdouble(-0.000000000000000000051066485848517600000)
    a2 = np.longdouble(0.0000000000000012806568632620900000)
    a3 = np.longdouble(-0.00000000000531035856252443000)
    a4 = np.longdouble(0.0000000086330792556790300)
    a5 = np.longdouble(-0.0000063412693200472300000)
    a6 = np.longdouble(0.0020307237682114700000000)
    b1 = np.longdouble(19.2031257127800000000000000)

#    return a1 * f ** 6 + a2 * f ** 5 + a3 * f ** 4 + a4 * f ** 3 + a5 * f ** 2 + a6 * f + b1
    return b1 + f*(a6 + f*(a5 + f*(a4 + f*(a3 + f*(a2 + f*a1)))))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = np.arange(50, 1801)
    plt.plot(f, gain_response(f), label="-40C")
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

The plot generated by my code looks like the one you got from Excel.  See if it works for you.

[image]

Comment: That makes sense especially since this behavior occurs as f increases. I'm not on the windows machine that was exhibiting this, but I will be tomorrow, and I'll be able to see if horner's rule fixes this.

Comment: I can promise that it does.  I used the code I posted to generate the plot that I show.  I'm running Python 3.11 on a MacBook Pro using PyCharm.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed it this morning. Thanks so much!

Comment: It's my great pleasure.  Glad it worked for you.